Interpretation of powers of adjacency matrix
Exercise:
Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a adjacency matrix of a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices.
I am struggling a little bit with the interpretation of the adjacency matrix. I know that if for example $a_{13}=2$, then there are two directed edges from vertex $1$ to vertex $3$.
For simplicity let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a $3$x$3$ matrix.
It is said that the entry $(i,j)$-th entry of $A^2$ can be interpreted as the generating function of all directed walks  of lenght $2$ from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$. I don't see how and why that could be seen that way. Especially the "generating function" terminology above confuses me.
As far as I know, given a sequence $(x_n)$, the generating function of this sequence is $G(x_n,z):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_n z^n$. But given a adjacency matrix, there is no sequence.
I tried to do an example but this didn't help either:
Consider for example the following adjacency matrix (of a graph G)
$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$
I calculated that,
$A^2=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$,
this would mean the "the generating function" of all directed walks from vertex $3$ to vertex $2$ is the $1$, i.e. $1 z^0+0z^1+0z^2+....$. But this just looks like gibberish to me. Or at least I can't see any meaning behind this "power series".
Thanks in advance for any help.

The generating function view of powers of the adjacency matrix is, well, niche at best. Most people that think about this concept never think about it with generating functions.
You can see a bit more of the generating function idea if you have a matrix with variable entries. For example, if $$A = \begin{bmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{bmatrix}$$ then the $(2,3)$ entry of $A^2$ is $a_{21}a_{13} + a_{22} a_{23} + a_{23} a_{33}$, and you can see how each term of this entry corresponds to one of the three possible walks from $2$ to $3$: the walks $(2,1,3)$, $(2,2,3)$, and $(2,3,3)$. (Note that by default, our variables are commutative, which means that - especially for higher powers of $A$ - this generating function only keeps track of which edges are used how many times, and not in which order.)
When you look at numerical examples, you substitute values for the variables, and this is really no different from substituting values in ordinary generating functions. For example:

You can think of $(w+x+y+z)^{10}$ as the generating function for the ways to choose a sequence of $10$ objects of $4$ different types; a term like $6300 w x^4 y^4 z$ tells us that there are $6300$ sequences that have one $w$, four $x$'s, four $y$'s, and one $z$.
If you set $w=0$ and set $x=y=1$, then you are saying: "I only want sequences without $w$'s, and furthermore I don't care to distinguish how many $x$'s or $y$'s they have." The resulting generating function $(2+z)^{10}$ has terms like $15360 z^3$ telling us that there are $15360$ sequences of length $10$ that have no $w$'s, some irrelevant number of $x$'s and $y$'s, and three $z$'s.

Similarly, if you do a partial substitution like $$A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & x \\ x & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & x & 0\end{bmatrix}$$ and then compute the $(2,3)$ entry of $A^2$ (which is now just $x^2$), you could think of this as saying "I only want to use edges in the cycle graph $C_3$, and instead of keeping track of each edge used, I only want to keep track of how many counterclockwise edges there are." Then the single term of $x^2$ says, "There is a single walk of length $2$ with these conditions, and it uses $2$ counterclockwise edges."
If you do a whole substitution, the interpretation as a generating function is rather tenuous. You could think of $(1+1+1+1)^{10}$ as the generating function for sequences of $10$ objects of $4$ different types, where you don't care to distinguish between the objects, but it's probably best to simply think of it as counting such sequences. Similarly, if $A$ is a numerical matrix, the $(i,j)$ entry of $A^n$ is best thought of as simply counting $i-j$ walks of length $n$.
Another relevant generating function, however, is $$I + xA + x^2 A^2 + x^3 A^3 + \dots = (I - x A)^{-1}$$ where $A$ is a numerical adjacency matrix. Here, each edge has a factor of $x$ in it, so the power of $x$ counts the number of edges in the walk, and we add up all powers of $xA$, so we include walks of all lengths. Thus, the $(i,j)$ entry of this matrix will be a generating function where the coefficient of $x^n$ is the number of $i-j$ walks of length $n$.

A very good explaination, thank you very much!
